# Testflight - Is it possible to automatically have test devices update to the latest .ipa build I upload without using the SDK?

Tags: ios, testflight

Testflight - Is it possible to automatically have test devices update to the latest .ipa build I upload without using the SDK?

Since they were bought, the SDK is no longer available. I'm a new user anyway... but I was wondering if there is a way to update to the latest build on the device automatically.

PS. Or do I have to login to the site manually and update from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using the SDK, which is unavailable since Apple bought the company and started integrating it into the iTunes Connect - Pre-release feature, it's impossible.

In the end one can use the iTunes Connect - Pre-release or turn to a OS X Server - Profile Manager + Xcode continuous integration for an in-house take at it.